# Amazon DynamoDB get all items in list of partition keys

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have single table design where I store user data and friends data. Having both partition and sort keys and looks like this:

| PK | SK | Username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USER#1 | USER#1 | Tom |
| USER#2 | USER#2 | Ben |
| USER#3 | USER#3 | Rob |
| USER#1 | FRIEND#2 |  |
| USER#2 | FRIEND#1 |  |
| USER#1 | FRIEND#3 |  |
| USER#3 | FRIEND#1 |  |

Now I want to get all friends of Tom ie (USER#1)
As you can see Tom is friend of both Ben and Rob.

To get the friends of tom I run

```
let params = {
    TableName : "table",
    KeyConditionExpression: "PK = :userId AND begins_with(SK, :friend)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":userId": {S:'USER#1'},
        ":friend": {S: "FRIEND#"}
    }
};
```

Now I got list USER#2, USER#3 in result. This is what I get from above query

| PK | SK | Username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USER#1 | FRIEND#2 |  |
| USER#1 | FRIEND#3 |  |

Next,  I need to get profile info of those users like username. At the moment I am looping and making other query to get user details. Running query in each loop is so inefficient.  How can I get list of all friends name using single query by providing list of PK as (USER#2 and USER#3)?

And this is what I expect

| PK | SK | Username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USER#2 | USER#2 | Ben |
| USER#3 | USER#2 | Rob |

Comment: What is your expected output? Your question is a bit unclear - what do you currently get back and what do you want?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - sorry i tried to make question as clear as possible. But i have now updated in case it can provide better insight.

Comment: thanks :) it really helps

Comment: If username is a string, your query should work - does the raw response set username to `null` or does the field just not exist?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary hmmm..

Comment: If you share your full code, there might be an issue there...

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary problem is not with code , its concept.

Comment: Your query is fine - DynamoDB doesn't exclude any properties unless you specify it in your query

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thank you but I guess you did not understood question completely.

Comment: Your issue as I understand is that username is not coming through - is username in the same table? If so, it should be. Your question is not reproducible.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Updated the question, if that is clearer.

Comment: It sounds like you are running multiple getItem operations in a loop.  You may want to consider performing a batchGetItem operation to fetch up to 100 items at once.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html

Comment: Do you need the entire profile for every single friend at once?  If not, would it be enough to store a few details on the friend record (e.g. USER#1, FRIEND#1, username, URL to profile info) and the application can present a URL to fetch the full users profile as needed.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan thank you. batchGetItem got limitation of performance and max of 100 results. Saving data in row is problem due to amount of cols and sync on update.

Comment: While the approach I mentioned isn't ideal, it's your best option with DynamoDB when working with a many-to-many relationship with highly-mutable data. 

It's tough to recommend a specific strategy without knowing the precise details of your access pattern.  If your application really needs 100+ *full* user profiles with each request and the performance of batchGetItem is not sufficient, you may want to explore a different database for this access pattern.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan - access pattern is exactly same what I specified in question. Not sure about " precise details of your access pattern"